# App sandbox not enabled error trying to upload my App

Tags: swift, sandbox, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox

I'm developing an App to open Microsoft Remote Desktop using just commands. This App work very well locally but when I tried to upload to Mac Store I received this error:

> ERROR ITMS-90296: "App sandbox not enabled. The following executables
>   must include the "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a
>   Boolean value of true in the entitlements property list: [(
>   "sse.itopia.pkg/Payload/StreetSmart Edge
>   Launcher.app/Contents/MacOS/StreetSmart Edge Launcher" )] Refer to App
>   Sandbox page at https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/app-sandbox/
>   for more information on sandboxing your app."

I used let path = "/bin/bash" as part of my code to execute commands.
The entitlements have the com.apple.security.app-sandbox key set as true and under Project Target->Capabilities, App Sandox is set to On.

```
func createRemoteDesktop(_ jSON : JSON) {

    let path = "/bin/bash"

    var arguments = ["-c","'/Applications/Microsoft Remote Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Remote Desktop' --script bookmark write GIMP --friendlyname '" + jSON["friendlyname"].stringValue + "' --hostname '" + jSON["hostname"].stringValue + "' --username '" + jSON["username"].stringValue + "' --password '" + jSON["password"].stringValue + "' --gatewayhostname '" + jSON["gatewayhostname"].stringValue + "' --remoteappprogram '" + jSON["remoteappprogram"].stringValue + "'"]

    var task = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: path, arguments: arguments)
    task.waitUntilExit()
}
```

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to the problem? I am currently hitting the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on your project in the project navigator
2. Click on capabilities
3. Switch app sandbox to "on"

Comment: Hi Major. Like I said Project Target->Capabilities, App Sandox is set to On.